# passing program arguments to spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

I have a spring boot batch application which use program arguments to get some files and manipulate it. the app works fine but i have problems when running the junit tests.
Here is my code :

```
 @Component
public class ApplicationArguments implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired private org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments appArgs;
    private String filePath;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        filePath = appArgs.getSourceArgs()[0];
    }
}
```

this bean is used by another one to build the full path :

```
@Component
public class InitPaths implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired private ApplicationArguments myAppArgs;
    private String fullPath;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        fullPath = myAppArgs.getFilePath(); //this will be null when launching tests
        fullPath.toString();//this will throw a NullPointerException if we run the test
    }
}
```

the application works fine using this command :

```
java -jar myApp.jar fileName.txt
```

is there any solution to pass the same argument to the junit test ?

I tried to use mocks but i had the same issue :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class BatchTest {

    @MockBean
    ApplicationArguments applicationArguments;
    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    InitPaths  initPaths;

    @Before
    public void before() {

        when(applicationArguments.getFilePath()).thenReturn("myCustomFile.dat");
    }

    @Test
    public void contextLoad() {
    }
}
```

Here is the error :

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Try to without `@InjectMocks` annotation,  it not need a for `SpringRunner.class`.

Comment: thanks @borino for your response. I tried it but i had the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because method `afterPropertiesSet()` in `InitPaths` have been running a earlier them `before` in test. Thats mean your mocked `ApplicationArguments` do not have any mocked behavior. From my perspective you might create new mocked `ApplicationArguments` with predefined behavior

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Import(ApplicationArgumentsTestConfig.class)
public class BatchTest {

@Autowired
InitPaths  initPaths;

@Test
public void contextLoad() {
}

public static class ApplicationArgumentsTestConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ApplicationArguments mockArg() {
        ApplicationArguments mocked = Mockito.mock(ApplicationArguments.class);
        Mockito.when(mocked.getFilePath()).thenReturn("test-mock-path");
        return mocked;
    }
 }
}
```

I just checked work for me.

Comment: it works perfectly. thanks a lot borino you are a life saver. i add some changes because i had an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the ApplicationArguments class (this is normal because i have no arguments). so i added the @Profile("!test") to ApplicationArguments class then i runed my test using the @ActiveProfiles("test") annotation.